# Sending specific hex data using scapy

Tags: python, hex, scapy

I want to send specific hex sequences e.g FF FF FF FF FF FF on wire using scapy without using the Raw option. Will finding the string equivalent of these hex sequences and using them as packet payload have the same effect since scapy will convert them to hex and send ?

Comment: Scapy does not send hex. Scapy will display your data as text but it is going to send them as raw bytes over the wire. Hexadecimal representation is just that, a representation of data.

Comment: Well If I give "ffffffffffff" as text input then scapy sends 66:66:66:66:66:66:66:66:66:66:66:66 on the wire. Is that not hex of the input text? Thanks

Comment: `0xFF` is `255` represented as an integer. So some code you have, edit in to your question your input and expected output. Some context around the question will also help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 2.x you can create the binary data from a hex string using the `binascii` module. I've used this to correctly set the duid in DHCPv6 request, just passing it to the option of the packet type.

For example

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('FFFFFFFFFFFF')
'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Passing that string to the payload should be all you need. Of course you can just type the string with `\x` escapes as above, but it's easier to represent it as a nice hex string and call `unhexlify` when you need the correct binary data.

Comment: I just looked at your answer. I tried the same thing last week and it works

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @msvalkon 's answer:

```
Scapy does not send hex. Scapy will display your data as text but it is going to send them as raw bytes over the wire. Hexadecimal representation is just that, a representation of data.
```

If we want to arrange payload with `0xff`, we can assign `payload = '\xff'`. And scapy will send `0xff` on the wire.

Full example for ICMP packet with 9 `0xff` bytes in payload:

```
~$ sudo scapy 
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
INFO: Can't import python-cryptography v1.7+. Disabled WEP decryption/encryption. (Dot11)
INFO: Can't import python-cryptography v1.7+. Disabled IPsec encryption/authentication.
WARNING: IPython not available. Using standard Python shell instead.
AutoCompletion, History are disabled.
                                      
                     aSPY//YASa       
             apyyyyCY//////////YCa       |
            sY//////YSpcs  scpCY//Pp     | Welcome to Scapy
 ayp ayyyyyyySCP//Pp           syY//C    | Version 2.4.3
 AYAsAYYYYYYYY///Ps              cY//S   |
         pCCCCY//p          cSSps y//Y   | https://github.com/secdev/scapy
         SPPPP///a          pP///AC//Y   |
              A//A            cyP////C   | Have fun!
              p///Ac            sC///a   |
              P////YCpc           A//A   | We are in France, we say Skappee.
       scccccp///pSP///p          p//Y   | OK? Merci.
      sY/////////y  caa           S//P   |             -- Sebastien Chabal
       cayCyayP//Ya              pY/Ya   |
        sY/PsY////YCc          aC//Yp 
         sc  sccaCY//PCypaapyCP//YSs  
                  spCPY//////YPSps    
                       ccaacs         
                                      
>>> a = ""
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     a += '\xff'
... 
>>> pkt = IP(dst = '10.5.2.3')/ICMP()/Raw(a)
>>> pkt
<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=10.5.2.3 |<ICMP  |<Raw  load='\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff' |>>>
>>> hexdump(pkt)
WARNING: No route found (no default route?)
0000  45 00 00 25 00 01 00 00 40 01 6E D0 00 00 00 00  E..%....@.n.....
0010  0A 05 02 03 08 00 F8 FE 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF  ................
0020  FF FF FF FF FF                                   .....
>>>
```